# self-mutating issues at the moment of change permisions

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am creating a self-mutation under Windows, but when I try to change my permissions page boundaries, it works under Dev C++, but the same code doesn't work under Visual Studio 2017.  Once I compile it works, but it always return me original function result 1, mutation 1 when it should be 42.

Dev C++

```
int change_page_permissions_of_address(void *addr) {
    // Move the pointer to the page boundary
    int page_size = getpagesize();
    DWORD dwOldProtect;

    addr -= (unsigned uintptr_t)addr % page_size; // it works under dev c++

    if(VirtualProtect(addr, page_size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&dwOldProtect) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2017

```
int change_page_permissions_of_address(void* address) {
    // Move the pointer to the page boundary

    unsigned char* addr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(address); // cast before operation

    int page_size = getpagesize();
    DWORD dwOldProtect;

    addr -= (uintptr_t)addr % page_size; // doesnt work under visual studio

    if (VirtualProtect(addr, page_size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

main

```
int main(){
    void *foo_addr = (void*)foo; 
    if(change_page_permissions_of_address(foo_addr) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while changing page permissions of foo(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // Call the unmodified foo()
    puts("Calling foo...");
    foo();

    // Change the immediate value in the addl instruction in foo() to 42
    unsigned char *instruction = (unsigned char*)foo_addr + 18;
    *instruction = 0x2A;

    // Call the modified foo()
    puts("Calling foo..., but I am the self-modifying");
    foo();

    return 0;    
}
```

[self-mutation_visual](https://godbolt.org/z/axu83H)

Comment: The Dev C++ code is non-standard, as you can't perform pointer arithmetic on a `void*` pointer.  The Visual Studio code is correct. But you did not define what "doesnt work" for you exactly. In any case, instead of calculating the page boundary manually, consider using [`VirtualQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualquery) instead and let it round down the address for you: "*`lpAddress` A pointer to the base address of the region of pages to be queried. **This value is rounded down to the next page boundary**.*"...

Comment: ... the returned `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` will contain the actual base address of the page region that the input address belongs to, and the byte size of the region.  With those values, you can then tweak the permissions of the region.

Comment: How do you know that `addr -= (uintptr_t)addr % page_size;` is the part that doesn't work?

Comment: because it was what visual studio is telling me the error come from , but how can I convert it to an standard code?

Comment: @yesii_0691 what is the actual error message?